# Unable to open "Remote Desktop Protocol" (RDP) URLs from command-line

Tags: network, remote-desktop, microsoft, 3rd-party

I am unable to open RDP URLs from the command-line.

Whenever I try to open RDP URL from command line by executing the following:

```
open rdp://localhost/
```

or any other IP address, I get the following error:

> The URL is not valid. Notify your network administrator.

I am able to connect to the host using **Microsoft Remote Desktop (8.0.43)**.

How do I open RDP connection using command-line?

---

To clarify, this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/54925/22781) claims that there is no command to access MS RD app, but it's not correct, since running the `open` command opens the app correctly, however there is the following error:

[image: Microsoft Remote Desktop - The URL is not valid. Notify your network administrator.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command-line arguments for "Remote Desktop Connection for Mac"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54918/command-line-arguments-for-remote-desktop-connection-for-mac)

Comment: It's not duplicate, as the other post doesn't make sense. I'm using the right syntax and `open` command opens MS RD app correctly. Secondly, [CoRD](https://github.com/dorianj/CoRD) is no longer being maintained as of August 16, 2015. My question is about this error related to MS RD specifically, not CoRD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Remote Desktop client URI scheme support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-uri), the correct syntax is:

```
open rdp://full%20address=s:localhost
```

This also works:

```
open rdp://address=s:localhost
```

---

For convenience, the following shell function can be defined:

```
# Compare two binary files.
# Usage: open-rdp ip.address
open-rdp() {
  open rdp://full%20address=s:$*
}
```

<sup>Note: The above code can be copy & pasted into terminal or added into shell startup rc files.</sup>

Usage:

```
open-rdp IP.Address
```